# Is Redux needed here or can I do it without?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to figure out what "id" I should have in my Challengedetail's ComponentDidMount file: `url:${process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE}/challengedetail/${id}`

Whenever a challenge gets clicked in the Allchallenges file a challengedetail page opens with as id that exact challenge that gets clicked. On the challengedetail page I want to print the title and description of the challenge.

I googled a bit around and it seems the only way to do this is with Redux? Or is there also a way without using Redux? How would that work?

---

**Allchallenges.js**

```
{this.state.searchChallenges.map(challenge =>(
    <Link to={`/challengedetail/${challenge._id}`}>
     <Challengebox key={challenge._id} id={challenge._id} title={challenge.title} description= 
     {challenge.description}/>
    </Link>
))}
```

---

**Challengedetail.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import DefaultLayout from "../layout/Default"
import './Challengedetail.css'
import Responsechallenge from '../components/Responsechallenge'
import axios from "axios"
import TakeChallenge from "../components/Takechallenge"

class Challengedetail extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()

        this.state = {
            title:"",
            description:"",
            responses: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        const challengeId = this.props.match.params.id       
        axios({
            method: "GET",
            url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE}/challengedetail/${challengeId}`,
            withCredentials: true
        })
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response.data)
            this.setState({
                title: response.data.title,
                description: response.data.description
            })
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log("Charles this is an error: ", error)
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <DefaultLayout>
                <div className="challengedetailpage">
                    <div className="headercontainer">
                        <div className="challengesectionbox">
                            <h1>{this.state.title}charles</h1>
                            <p>{this.state.description}ffff</p>
                        </div>

                        <div className="takechallengebox">
                            <TakeChallenge/>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="responsechallenges">
                        <Responsechallenge/>
                        <Responsechallenge/>
                        <Responsechallenge/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </DefaultLayout>
        )
    }
}

export default Challengedetail
```

---

**App.js**

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">

    <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
          <Route path="/profile" component={Profile} />
          <Route path="/allchallenges" component={Allchallenges} />
          <Route path="/friends" component={Friends} />
          <Route path="/startchallenge" component={Startchallenge} />
          <Route path="/challengedetail/:id" component={Challengedetail} />
          <Route path="/about" component={About} />
          <Route path="/todo" component={Todo} />
    </Switch>

    </div>
  );
}
```

---

**BACKEND**

```
// request challenge info
router.get("/challengedetail/:id", (req,res) => {
  Challenge
  .findById({req.params.id})
  .then(response => {
    console.log("Charles")
    res.json(response)
    console.log("Charles")
  })
  .catch(error => {
    res.json(error)
  })
})
```

---

**ERRORS IN CONSOLE**

```
xhr.js:178 GET http://localhost:3000/challengedetail/5ed6bbd9aef7f148c83baeb2 404 (Not Found)

Charles this is an error:  Error: Request failed with status code 404
        at createError (createError.js:16)
        at settle (settle.js:17)
        at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:61)
```

---

**.Env file BACKEND:**

```
client_origin_a=http://localhost:3001
client_origin_b=https://localhost:3001
```

---

**.Env file FRONTEND:**

```
REACT_APP_API_BASE=http://localhost:3000
```

Comment: all your doing is mapping over an array of challenges and then depending on which one is clicked rendering that specific view. what makes you think you need Redux?

Comment: From what I'm understanding you are redirecting from a list to a detail page. If it's the case you could pass the id as a route parameter and then access the id inside component did mount. No need for Redux.

Comment: how do you mean "passing the id as a router parameter"? How does that work?

Comment: @charlesbxl you are using `<Link to={`/challengedetail/${challenge._id}`}>` so I'm guessing somewhere you have defined the route `challengedetail/:id`? With this setup you can then access the route params whenever the route is accessed. If you are using react-router-dom you can have a look at: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params.

Comment: @DanielGrima: Hey thanks a lot for the explanation. I'm afraid I still don't fully get it. I added my Routes in my question and was wondering if you could exactly tell me what I should change?

Comment: I've posted an answer to help explain better how to achieve this.

Comment: Is your backend server running on port 3000 ? @charlesbxl

Answer (score 0):

**Route Configuration**

If you need to access route params firstly set the route to accept a parameter. In your case an id is all that's needed. Below you can see the editted routing configuration. `/challengedetail` has been updated to `/challengedetail/:id`.

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">

    <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
          <Route path="/profile" component={Profile} />
          <Route path="/allchallenges" component={Allchallenges} />
          <Route path="/friends" component={Friends} />
          <Route path="/startchallenge" component={Startchallenge} />
          <Route path="/challengedetail/:id" component={Challengedetail} />
          <Route path="/about" component={About} />
          <Route path="/todo" component={Todo} />
    </Switch>

    </div>
  );
}
```

**Accessing Route Param**

Now with the above configuration the `Challengedetail` component can check if in the route a value that corresponds to `:id` has been sent. You can do this by accessing the props and check the `match` object.

Example:

```js
class Challengedetail extends React.Component {
    // constructor...

    componentDidMount(){
        // get id from url
        const challengeId = this.props.match.params.id;

        axios({
            method: "GET",
            url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE}/challengedetail/${challengeId}`,
            withCredentials: true
        })
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response.data)
            this.setState({
                title: response.data.title,
                description: response.data.description
            })
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log("Charles this is an error: ", error)
        })
    }

    // render...
}
```

With that logic when the component is mounted, you are extracting the id from the URL, and then calling the server to get the data you need.

**Server Errors**

So I just realised that you updated the question... I don't think you have correctly set up your application with regards to `REACT_APP_API_BASE`. You need to have a `.env` in the root folder and create the `REACT_APP_API_BASE` value.

Example:

```
REACT_APP_API_BASE=http://localhost:4000
```

Remember UI and Backend will run on different ports therefore you need different ports on localhost as well. 4000 is just an example in this case, make sure that your Backend and UI are different ports, my guess is that you have both UI and Backend on the same port - that won't work.

Have a look at this to see how to set up your configuration: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/.

Comment: thanks man this is great advice. I have updated my code in my question above. The problem that I am still facing now is that I am not receiving a response from the server back.The console shows me the catch error. Any idea why that is?

Comment: You're welcome, if the answer helped you please accept the answer. With regards to the issue you're facing now I'm afraid I can't help you that much, it could be number of things. It depends on the API you are calling, one thing I suggest is have a look at the HTTP error code and the error you are logging and investigate from there.

Comment: Updated my answer to cater for the server issues you're having.

Comment: Hi! I have added my 2 .env files in my question (both for frontend & backend). Could you please exactly tell me what needs to be changed? I am not sure if there are any server problems here as I am correctly posting/getting info from elsewhere in my application

Comment: any idea here? any other info you need?

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue could be, only thing I can say is try to debug your code both from UI and backend. With a 404 error it looks like the URL you are calling is incorrect. If you are sure that the URL is correct in some cases APIs return 404 when the record does not exist.. as in does a record with id `5ed6bbd9aef7f148c83baeb2` really exist? Apart from that I can't help much I'm sorry

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your `React` app is running on port 3000. So analysing the error, i must say that your environment variable `REACT_APP_API_BASE` is `undefined` due to which you're falling back to `localhost:3000` or otherwise the environment variable has been mistakenly set to `localhost:3000` and hence you are unable to hit your backend API.

Please check your environment variable and confirm that you're correctly hitting your backend APIs.

Comment: Hi! I have added my 2 .env files in my question (both for frontend & backend). Could you please exactly tell me what needs to be changed? I am not sure if there are any server problems here as I am correctly posting/getting info from elsewhere in my application.

Comment: Blacklisted: any idea here?

Comment: First you have to debug your specific API. e.g. try hitting 
http://localhost:3000/challengedetail/5ed6bbd9aef7f148c83baeb2
using postman to see if there's a response or not. If you get what you need on the postman side, you're good on the API side. Please share your results then.